# Dynamically add divs into another div in random order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to shuffle a list of keywords and put them into individual divs within a text slideshow.

Here's my script:

```
var keys = ["dancing.", "computers.", "food.", "movies.", "singing.", "hiking.", "math.", "music.", "reading.", "cars.", "laughing.", "animals.", "cupcakes.", "shopping.", "soccer.", "Europe.", "photography.", "volunteering.", "outerspace.", "traveling.", "guitar.", "painting.", "children.", "boats.", "science.", "art.", "cheerleading.", "Einstein.", "teaching.", "politics.", "waterskiing.", "volleyball.", "whittling.", "volleyball.", "running.", "comedy.", "theater.", "Africa."];

keys.sort(function() { return Math.floor(Math.random()*3 -1)});

for(i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    ("<div>" + keys[i] + "</div>").appendTo("slideshow");   
}

function randomize(myArray) {
  var i = myArray.length;
  if ( i == 0 ) return false;
  while ( --i ) {
     var j = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( i + 1 ) );
     var tempi = myArray[i];
     var tempj = myArray[j];
     myArray[i] = tempj;
     myArray[j] = tempi;
   }
}
```

---

```
<td class="align-top">
   <div class="slideshow"></div>
</td>
```

---

Any ideas? I also think I have a bad blend of javascript and jQuery. Could you help me clean this up?

Comment: I think you are missing a `$` before `("<div>" + keys[i] + "</div>")` and you have to pass the correct selector to `appendTo`: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/. There are no elements with tag `slideshow`. You are looking for the class selector.

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort *compareFunction(a, b) must always returns (sic) the same value when given a specific pair of elements a and b as its two arguments*. Your sort function violates this rule, no?

Comment: To sort an array randomly try `keys.sort(function() { return Math.random()-0.5; });`. @ta.speot.is - this does violate that rule, but nevertheless it works for random sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
keys.sort(function() { return Math.random() - 0.5; });

var $slideshow = $(".slideshow");
for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    $slideshow.append("<div>" + keys[i] + "</div>");   
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XpyYX/1/

Your code didn't work because on this line:

```
("<div>" + keys[i] + "</div>").appendTo("slideshow");
```

You left out the `$` or `jQuery` from before the opening `(`, and because you want to append to `".slideshow"` (with a `.`) to select the element by class. It would work like this:

```
$("<div>" + keys[i] + "</div>").appendTo(".slideshow");
```

...but it should be more efficient to cache the reference to the slideshow element.

Also your random sort was overly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while(keys.length > 0)
{
    var k = Math.floor(Math.random()*keys.length);
    $("<div>"+keys[k]+"</div>").appendTo('.slideshow');
    keys.slice(k, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
var keys = ["dancing", "computers", "food", "movies", "singing", "hiking", "math", "music", "reading", "cars", "laughing", "animals", "cupcakes", "shopping", "soccer", "Europe", "photography", "volunteering", "outerspace", "traveling", "guitar", "painting", "children", "boats", "science", "art", "cheerleading", "Einstein", "teaching", "politics", "waterskiing", "volleyball", "whittling", "volleyball", "running", "comedy", "theater", "Africa"];

var el=document.getElementById('slideshow'),
    temp=document.createElement('div');
for(var i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
    var current=temp.cloneNode(false);
    current.appendChild(document.createTextNode(keys[i]+'.'));
    var position=Math.floor(Math.random()*(el.childNodes.length+1));
    if(position==el.childNodes.length){
        el.appendChild(current);
    }else{
        el.insertBefore(current,el.childNodes[position]);
    }
}
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/UFdbm/

**Notes**:

- You can remove the dots at the end of the elements and add it later
- See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort. If you use `.sort(compareFunction)`, `compareFunction(a, b)` must always returns the same value when given a specific pair of elements `a` and `b` as its two arguments. If inconsistent results are returned then the sort order is undefined. So you can't use a function which returns random values when you sort the array.

**EDIT**:

You can simplify it a bit using jQuery:

```
var keys = ["dancing", "computers", "food", "movies", "singing", "hiking", "math", "music", "reading", "cars", "laughing", "animals", "cupcakes", "shopping", "soccer", "Europe", "photography", "volunteering", "outerspace", "traveling", "guitar", "painting", "children", "boats", "science", "art", "cheerleading", "Einstein", "teaching", "politics", "waterskiing", "volleyball", "whittling", "volleyball", "running", "comedy", "theater", "Africa"];

var el=$('#slideshow');
for(var i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
    var current=$("<div>"+keys[i]+".</div>");
    var position=Math.floor(Math.random()*(el.children().length+1));
    if(position==el.children().length){
        el.append(current);
    }else{
        current.insertBefore(el.children().eq(position));
    }
}
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/UFdbm/1/

Comment: _"If inconsistent results are returned then the sort order is undefined"_ - Maybe so, but if the idea is to sort randomly it seems to work fine. This technique works in FF, so Mozilla can't have _too_ strong an objection, and it also works in IE and Chrome. Are you aware of a browser where it doesn't work?

Comment: @nnnnnn No, I am not. But that doesn't mean that that it works on all browsers. And, independently of that, bad practices should be avoided...

Answer (score 0):

```
var keys = ["dancing.", "computers.", "food.", "movies.", "singing.", "hiking.", "math.", "music.", "reading.", "cars.", "laughing.", "animals.", "cupcakes.", "shopping.", "soccer.", "Europe.", "photography.", "volunteering.", "outerspace.", "traveling.", "guitar.", "painting.", "children.", "boats.", "science.", "art.", "cheerleading.", "Einstein.", "teaching.", "politics.", "waterskiing.", "volleyball.", "whittling.", "volleyball.", "running.", "comedy.", "theater.", "Africa."];

var insertionSort = function (arr) {
    var len = arr.length, i = -1, j, tmp;

    while (len--) {
        tmp = arr[++i];
        j = i;
        while (j-- && arr[j] > tmp) {
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
        }
        arr[j + 1] = tmp;
    }
};

insertionSort(keys);
alert(keys);
for(i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    $("<div>"+keys[k]+"</div>").appendTo('.slideshow');

}
```

try this out